# How do I aggregate and avg the time between two dates?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assuming the below is my element structure. How can I SHELL query the mongodb and get the avg difference (average length) each trip took for every trip in the db? I am guessing subtracting dates? But then how to subtract and then avg?

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5445ab058767000062"
},
"comment": null,
"scheduled_request": false,
"status": "blah",
"timestamp_started": {
    "$date": "2014-10-21T00:38:28.990Z"
},
"timestamp_transaction_complete": {
    "$date": "2014-10-21T00:49:12.990Z"
},
"user_id": "5445a9000057"
```

UDPATE ========
Here is my query

```
db.ambulance_requests.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "avg_time": {
      "$avg": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$timestamp_transaction_complete",
          "$timestamp_started"
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

AND MY RESULT (from a Mac Terminal Shell):

```
{ "_id" : null, "avg_time" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) and [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) by applying them in a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage. For "everything", use `null` for the grouping key:

```
db.trips.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "avg_time": {
      "$avg": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$timestamp_completed", 0 ] },
          { "$ifNull": [ "$timestamp_started", 0 ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

When you [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) on BSON Date object from another, the difference is returned as the milliseconds interval between them. This is also a generally handy technique for extracting the milliseconds value for other purposes.

Your single document as supplied:

```
{
    "comment" : null,
    "scheduled_request" : false,
    "status" : "blah",
    "timestamp_started" : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:38:28.990Z"),
    "timestamp_completed" : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:49:12.990Z"),
    "user_id" : "5445a9000057"
}
```

The result from your single document in the question:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "avg_time" : 644000.0
}
```

Comment: I runt his and the the avg_time is 0?  I know that isn't accurate.   { "_id" : null, "avg_time" : 0 }

Comment: @jdog Actually it's not even possible, and If I use the data presented in the question then of course I get the difference between the two dates. You are doing something incorrectly. Show some more documents in your question, and use the actual mongo shell output, rather than the dump from your IDE or wherever you are getting that serialized format from please.

Comment: Maybe some of the timestamps don't have data? Would this break it?

Comment: @jdog What update? You should be looking yourself. Your question data is copied and inserted into a collection and the query and results are copied and pasted in the answer. From your data. If you don't get the same result you are doing something differently, and incorrect. All I see in your question is that you are referencing a field that does not appear to exist in your data

Comment: I changed the field name in the data above. It now contains the real fields. I have also shown the actual query I am running and the actual response from the shell.

Comment: @jdog Add $ifNull statements in to account for any fields that might not be present. Please also learn the lesson by example that you need to provide your data "as is" when asking. If you need to ask someone how to do it, then you are likely going to get it wrong when trying to interpret how to apply it to something that is different that what you actually ask.

Comment: I understand. I was obfuscating the data. I see the issue. The timestamps are down one level in a field called "Run". So all timestamps are inside a Run field, not at the top level as listed in the document above.

Comment: @jdog Not really the space for chatting.  You asked a question and it got answered, The answer self contains the data you asked with, the query to get the result and the response from the query showing the correct interval. This question is answered. Work it out or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/nFO54i5GIXU

if **finishedAt** dose not exist in a doc then skip that document from avg calculation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "finishedAt": {
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "tags.name": "Canada"
        },
        {
          "tags.name": "ABC"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "avg_time": {
        "$avg": {
          "$subtract": [
            "$finishedAt",
            "$createdAt"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```